# Unable to understand dictionaries behavior when simulating a linked list

Tags: python, dictionary, linked-list

I am trying to simulate linked lists in python using dictionaries - `h` (stands for head) and `t` (stands for tail):

```
t = {"value": 5, "next": None}
h = t
```

I add a new node `n1` as value of the key "next" in `t`:

```
n1 = {"value": 10, "next": None}
t["next"] = n1

print(t)
# {'value': 5, 'next': {'value': 10, 'next': None}}

print(h)
# {'value': 5, 'next': {'value': 10, 'next': None}}
```

I understand that is because both `h` and `t` are referring to the same memory address at this moment.

This is also confirmed by

```
print(id(h))
# 2429471179008

print(id(t))
# 2429471179008
```

I now changed the value of `t` to the node `n1`:

```
t = n1
print(t)
# {'value': 10, 'next': None}

print(h)
# {'value': 5, 'next': {'value': 10, 'next': None}}
```

My understanding is that at this point `h` and `t` will start referring to different memory addresses.

This is also confirmed by

```
print(id(h))
# 2429471179008

print(id(t))
# 2429470939776
```

Now I add one more new node `n2` as value of the key "next" in `t`:

```
n2 = {"value": 16, "next": None}
t["next"] = n2

print(t)
# {'value': 10, 'next': {'value': 16, 'next': None}}

print(h)
# {'value': 5, 'next': {'value': 10, 'next': {'value': 16, 'next': None}}}
```

Why is that so? How did the change to `t` impact `h` and that too in this fashion?

I was expecting the output of `print(h)` to still show up as `{'value': 5, 'next': {'value': 10, 'next': None}}`.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Comment: You should just use [this](https://pythontutor.com/) to visualize it. In essence, `h['next']` is always the same dictionary (named `t` and also `n1` at the end).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My understanding is that at this point `h` and `t` will start referring to different memory addresses.

True, but `h["next"]` and `t` reference the same.

Here is a visualisation of all the actions you performed:

```
t = {"value": 5, "next": None}
h = t
```

The resulting state can be pictured like this:

```
  t     h
  ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐
│ value: 5   │
│ next: None │
└────────────┘
```

```
n1 = {"value": 10, "next": None}
t["next"] = n1
```

The resulting state can be pictured like this:

```
  t     h          n1
  ↓     ↓          ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 5   │   │ value: 10  │
│ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Then you prepare a next operation with:

```
t = n1
```

```
        h          n1    t
        ↓          ↓     ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 5   │   │ value: 10  │
│ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Here you can already see that although `h` and `t` reference different nodes, they are not independent. `h["next"]` references the same node as `t`.

Then the script continues with:

```
n2 = {"value": 16, "next": None}
```

The resulting state can be pictured like this:

```
        h          n1    t          n2
        ↓          ↓     ↓          ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 5   │   │ value: 10  │   │ value: 16  │
│ next: ────────►│ next: None │   │ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

The following statement:

```
t["next"] = n2
```

...leads to this:

```
        h          n1    t          n2
        ↓          ↓     ↓          ↓
┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐   ┌────────────┐
│ value: 5   │   │ value: 10  │   │ value: 16  │
│ next: ────────►│ next: ────────►│ next: None │
└────────────┘   └────────────┘   └────────────┘
```

Here we have `t` still referencing a *sublist* of `h`.

I hope this clarifies it.